# How can I check if I'm using the AMDGPU-PRO driver?

Tags: arch-linux, amd-graphics

I've installed the [amdgpu-pro-libgl](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/amdgpu-pro-libgl/) drivers from AUR, hoping it would fix an issue.

Pikaur didn't seem to trigger any kind of recompilation, or DKMS or mkinitcpio, but from what I understand, the package includes some kernel components.. How can I check that AMDGPU-PRO drivers are indeed running?

Comment: Does `lshw -c video` show a graphics driver under `configuration: driver=`?

Comment: @kemotep It does. It shows amdgpu

Comment: `lspci -k` also shows `amdgpu`, and under "kernel modules" lists *ONLY* amdgpu. My understanding is that if the pro drivers were enabled, they would show up there, as well

Comment: Then you are using the proprietary AMD graphics driver. If you were using the open source driver it would be `radeon`. If `lsmod | grep radeon` returns nothing then you are using proprietary driver.  Or at least it is on Debian.

Comment: @kemotep are you sure? `radeon` is the name for the old open-source drivers.

Comment: What do you mean? If you are using `radeon` you are not using `amdgpu`. If you are using `amdgpu` then you are not using `radeon`. At least that is the case if you are using Debian or a Debian-based distro. With Arch, on the Wiki they discuss both `amdgpu` and `amdgpu pro` as being two different things but nothing I can find says that `amdgpu` is _not_ the proprietary driver thus if you everything is reporting that you are using `amdgpu` you should be using the proprietary driver.

Comment: @kemotep it's the first line of the article: "AMDGPU is the open source graphics driver for the latest AMD Radeon graphics cards."  `amdgpu` is the name of the open-source drivers for the latest graphics cards. `radeon` is the name of the open-source drivers for the older cards. Both `amdgpu` and  `radeon` are open-source drivers.

Comment: Odd, in Debian the distinction is Radeon for open source and amdgpu for proprietary. I feel that Arch could do better to differentiate the two. It appears if you installed the library as it says thats all you need to do. Is your performance lacking or are you missing an instruction set?

Comment: @kemotep thanks for taking the time to try to help! If I pass `amdgpu.dc=1` or don't pass anything to the kernel, HDMI sound works but inverting colours does not. If I pass `amdgpu.dc=0`, inverting colours works but HDMI sound does not. Just trying to get both working at the same time

Comment: That is very frustrating.You are not alone though. [On the Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238189) I found a post with a very similar issue to yourself. [This wiki talk page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:AMDGPU) also has people discussing the same issue.

Comment: @kemotep ya so many posts about this. I think easiest fix is actually to code a compositor that will do colour inversion. Video drivers are very complex. There are kernel components, firmware, drivers, X drivers, and all of those seem to come in both open-source and proprietary flavours, and there are different drivers for different generations of graphics card chipsets. Then HDMI audio seems to be pass through the video components but also has its own drivers. A lot of moving parts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if it is the only way, but I do it as such: I run

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor string" | cut -f2 -d":" | xargs
```

If it returns `X.Org` or `AMD`, then the open source driver is active. If it returns `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.`, then the proprietary driver is active.

See the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU_PRO#How_to_ensure_you_are_using_AMDGPU-PRO_driver) for details.

Comment: Note: If you run "progl glmark2", you see there `GL_VENDOR:     ATI Technologies Inc.`. Probably glmark2 uses its own source of strings.